# Locationtracking with cell towers, reduce noise

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, location

I'm tracking the users position to have a travel log. For this I use cell tower triangulation. My app is notified about major location changes and I save the location to a db. Later I try to reduce the recorded noise.

Everything is working fine, except that I sometimes record virtual jumps between cell towers as shown below:

[image: zoomed out]
[image: zoomed in]

During the recording the user was not traveling.

I tried to reduce the noise with this algorithm, but it isn't working.
Do you have other ideas how to remove it?

```
var invalidLocationIDs = [String]()

        for index in 0...points.count-3 {

            let point0 = points[index+0]
            let point1 = points[index+1]
            let point2 = points[index+2]

            let location0 = CLLocation(latitude: point0.latitude, longitude: point0.longitude)
            let location1 = CLLocation(latitude: point1.latitude, longitude: point1.longitude)
            let location2 = CLLocation(latitude: point2.latitude, longitude: point2.longitude)

            let distanceA = location0.distance(from: location1)
            let distanceB = location0.distance(from: location2)

            if distanceB < distanceA {
                invalidLocationIDs.append(point2.locationID)
            }
        }
        deleteLocationsWithIDs(locationIDs: invalidLocationIDs)
```

This is the algorithm to track the locations:

```
self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
                    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 200
                    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
                    self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
                    self.locationManager.activityType = .other
```

Comment: Please show your location managers configuration.

Comment: I have added the location manger